# Convert mm/dd/yyyy into mysql timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I've been trying for about two hours to get this working with no luck.  I'm trying to convert a date that's entered like 11/18/2012 into a mysql timestamp but everything I've tried just ends up as either 0000-00-00 00:00:00 or NULL in the database :( I'm using PHP + MYSQL so a solution in either would be great

Comment: Please also post your attempt, so that we can skip what doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert string to date php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711952/convert-string-to-date-php)

Comment: I've tried a bunch of stuff...
using mysql I tried UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('$release_date','%m/%d/%y')) and UNIX_TIMESTAMP($release_date) in php I tried $release_date = strtotime($_POST['release_date']);  and some other stuff but I don't have the code anymore

Comment: @Jordan try my answer below

Comment: @Jordan `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('$release_date','%m/%d/%y'))` returns an integer, so you can't really insert it into a timestamp column. Try `TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('$release_date','%m/%d/%y'))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try This

```
 $release_date=$_POST['release_date'];
    echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($release_date));
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked perfectly :)  Sorry for the newb question but I've never had to do this before and I spent forever trying to figure it out myself before asking, this is what I used;
$release_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($_POST['release_date']));

Thanks again! :) :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) to the rescue!

```
$datetime = new DateTime($alternativeFormat);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // mysql format
```

It's also possible to leave the altering of the data by MySQL, but I advice against it. By using the `DateTime` object you leave your query open to support other formats aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('11/18/2012','%m/%d/%Y'))
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/4363/0

You stated that you tried:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('$release_date','%m/%d/%y'))
```

The reason this doesn't work is because `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`'s return type is unsigned integer, not `TIMESTAMP`. This is why you can't insert it into a `TIMESTAMP` column

Comment: 11/18 is clearly m/d, not d/m.  Edited.  OP would probably be using this in an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement, but the point is you replace the bare string in the SQL with a call to STR_TO_DATE('bare string', 'format string').

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `strtotime()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Or exploding on '/' and then using `mktime()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

```
$parts = explode('/', $date);
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $parts[0], $parts[1], $parts[2]);
```

Or any of the other suggestions in answers posted here?

Answer (score 0):

My favorite method:

```
$date = '10/1/2012';
$mysqlDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this.

```
$sDate = '11/18/2012';

$aDate = explode('/', $sDate);

$sMySQLTimestamp = sprintf(
   '%s-%s-%s 00:00:00',
    $aDate[2],
    $aDate[0],
    $aDate[1]
);

var_dump($sMySQLTimestamp);
> string(19) "2012-11-18 00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

can you enter that example date as 2012/11/18 ?

if yes use

```
select convert('2012/11/18' ,DATETIME)
```

or you can use

```
 select convert(str_to_date('11/18/2012','%m/%d/%Y'),DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer will depend upon exactly what you're trying to do, but in most cases it is a combination of these things:

1. Use a DateTime object, rather than a string, to represent the timestamp in PHP. (Convert it on input rather than when writing to the database).
2. Use a database interface that has placeholders, and when filling in a value that's a DateTime, automatically converts them to the appropriate string format

This keeps you from having to convert to, or even know, the native format expected by MySQL.