# How to convert mm-dd-yyyy to 2017-09-18T13:20:47-07:00 format

Tags: php, datetime, soap

I am working on soap EFS(electronic fund source)API. I have to get date form user which will be in `mm-dd-yyyy` and I have to pass this date as param in `2017-09-18T13:20:47-07:00` format.

How to convert data in 2017-09-18T13:20:47-07:00 format ?

Comment: Please try unix_timestamp() given in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625093/convert-mm-dd-yyyy-into-mysql-timestamp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: @Qirel no pl see my question specially the date format.

Comment: @TavishAggarwal unix_timestamp is mysql function. I have no database data i just want to convert date to given format. The date will come from POST data

Comment: You wish to convert from one format to another, yes? That thread shows how. But if you just have `MM-DD-YYYY`, you're missing some information (the specific time), so you already have an issue there - you need to convert from a full datetime, otherwise it's assumed to be 00:00:00.

Comment: @Qirel I have date in post data in this format (09-18-2017) I need to convert this date in 2017-09-18T13:20:47-07:00 this format.

Comment: Yes, you said that already - but how can you get the time (not date)? How do you get `13:20:47`? Through magic?

Comment: OK thats not the issue ok i will add it.  So suppose i have date like 09-18-2017 13:20:47 then how can I get "T" and that -07:00 ? what is this ?

Comment: See the flagged dupe :-) I suggest using a `DateTime` object, makes it easier. The `-07:00` is a timezone offset.

Answer (score 1):

Try below method for convert Date for soap as per [PHP DOCUMENT](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php)
Also, you have to pass time which is not in question. Below is not final answer but you can go throw something like this.

```
echo $dt->format('YY "-" MM "-" DD "T" HH ":" II ":" SS tzcorrection');
```

Comment: how can I get "T" and that -07:00 ? what is this ?